# Why am I getting TypeError in the Flask code?

Tags: python, flask

I was executing the  following Flask code and then I get the following error.

`TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either 
 returned None or ended without a return statement.`

I'm not quite sure what it means and what's wrong in my code.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import urllib.request
import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__ ,template_folder='template')
namep = "PewDiePie"
namet = "TSeries"
key = "MY_API_KEY"

@app.route("/")
def function_main():
 datat = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername="+namep+"&key="+key).read()
 datap = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername="+namet+"&key="+key).read()
 subt = json.loads(datat)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
 subsp = json.loads(datap)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
 def main():
   return render_template('template\index.html', subsp = subsp, subt = subt)#Sends the integers to index.html to get printed in the Flask server

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @NotMyName, why you put a return of the route in the main function? you don't need to do that. just return a template render pass the html template path and pass the data, then you will get the result what you want (as long as your code above the render template not give an error) :)

Comment: Thanks a ton man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import urllib.request
import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__ ,template_folder='template')
namep = "PewDiePie"
namet = "TSeries"
key = "MY_API_KEY"

@app.route("/")
def function_main():
 datat = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername="+namep+"&key="+key).read()
 datap = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername="+namet+"&key="+key).read()
 subt = json.loads(datat)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
 subsp = json.loads(datap)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
 return render_template('template\index.html', subsp = subsp, subt = subt)#Sends the integers to index.html to get printed in the Flask server

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Comment: What's my problem?

Comment: Direct return from function_main().

Comment: Oh.... thanks for the correction!